# Load *.vtl file from remote location

Tags: velocity, dotcms, vtl

is it possible in dotCMS to parse a vtl file from a remote source?

```
// this doesn't seem to work
#dotParse("https://some.random.source.com/vtl/index.vtl")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not normally and it would be very easy to write a plugin to do it.  Without writing any java code, it should be possible to do something like this:

```
#set($code = $import.read("https://some.random.source.com/vtl/index.vtl"))
$render.eval($context, $code)
```

The downside is that it will probably be much slower than just rendering a vtl in dotcms.